# How to make a LabVIEW front panel element invisible non-programmatically?

Tags: user-interface, labview

When designing the front panel of a LabVIEW application, there's no way to render controls invisible except programmatically: connecting a False constant to a "Visible" property node somewhere on the block diagram where it gets run before anything else.

Isn't there any way to do it from the front panel designer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two options -

1. Right click the control and select Advanced>>Hide Control.
2. Go the the diagram, right click the control's terminal and select Hide Control. This is also useful when you want to unhide the control and is easier to access.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't see that before!